# What is the difference between jQuery's mouseout() and mouseleave()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseout, mouseleave

What is the difference between jQuery's mouseout() and mouseleave()?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ are useful

Comment: Note: equivalent is `mouseover`, and equivalent to `mouseleave` is `mouseenter`.

Answer (score 111):

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: mouseover vs. mouseenter: https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/945pv53h/3/ (mouseout & mouseleave equivalently)

Comment: Explanation above gets much more clear when seeing both methods working and the difference between them, worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

There can be times when `mouseout` is a better choice than `mouseleave`.

For example, let's say you've created a tooltip that you want displayed next to an element on `mouseenter`. You use `setTimeout` to prevent the tooltip from popping up instantly. You clear the timeout on `mouseleave` using `clearTimeout` so if the mouse leaves the tooltip won't be displayed. **This will work 99% of the time.**

But now let's say the element you have a tooltip attached to is a button with a `click` event, and let's also assume this button prompts the user with either a `confirm` or `alert` box. The user clicks the button and the `alert` fires. The user pressed it fast enough that your tooltip didn't have a chance to pop up (so far so good).

The user presses the `alert` box OK button, and the mouse leaves the element. But since the browser page is now in a locked state, no javascript will fire until the OK button has been pressed, meaning your `mouseleave` event **WILL NOT FIRE**. After the user presses OK the tooltip will popup (which is not what you wanted).

Using `mouseout` in this case would be the appropriate solution because it will fire.

Comment: Could you explain why `mouseout` in that case will fire? Wouldn't the browser be still in locked state for `mouseout`?

Answer (score 10):

jQuery API doc:

`mouseout`

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves out of the Inner element in this example, a mouseout event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger the bound mouseout handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for .mouseleave() for a useful alternative.

So `mouseleave` is a custom event, which was designed because of the above reason.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 4):

Event Mouseout will trigger when mouse leaves the selected element and also when mouse leaves it's child elements also.

Event Mouseleave element will trigger when pointer will leave the selected element only.

Reference: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem using plan Javascript instead of jquery, but they're some how related and I'll leave my two cents in case someone else is on the search nowadays.

I was trying to use the `mouseout` event on a navigation menu. The parent `div` had a submenu composed of a list of `ul`s elements. When I tried to navigate to the `div` children elements the `mouseout` event was fired. This was not my desired output.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event)

> mouseout is also delivered to an element if the cursor enters a child
> element, because the child element obscures the visible area of the
> element.

And that was the issue.

The `mouseleave` event did not have this issue. Just using it made things work for me.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event