# Mouseup and Mousedown

Tags: jquery, mousedown, mouseup

So I want the buttons to change style when mouse is down, and return to previous when it goes up. I have this code:

```
$('#divMenu > #menu li a').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css({
  'font-size': '25px',  
  'color': 'red'     
  });               
}).mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css({
  'font-size': '30px',  
  'color': 'black'     
  });               
});
```

The problem is, that when I have mouse down, but take it away of my object and not release immediately, font size and color stays 25px and red. What should I do to pass that?

**EDIT:** JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h64Uz/

Comment: Can you post a JsFiddle? With the HTML too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a mouseout as well.

```
$('#divMenu > #menu li a').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css({
  'font-size': '25px',  
  'color': 'red'     
  });               
}).mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css({
  'font-size': '30px',  
  'color': 'black'     
  });               
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).css({
  'font-size': '30px',  
  'color': 'black'     
  });               
});
```

Your event code sets the css when the mouse is clicked. Once you move away it can't register a mouseup. But on leaving it will register a mouseout event.

Comment: Works just fine, didn't really think of that, shame on me. anyway, thank you, sir

Comment: mouseout() will trigger when the mouse leaves child elements, which is often not desireable. mouseleave() is better.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a `mouseleave()` event you can use to supplement the existing code:

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming you are using `jQuery` version 1.7 or above):

```
$('#divMenu > #menu li a').on("mousedown", function () {
  $(this).css({
    'font-size': '25px',
      'color': 'red'
  });
}).on("mouseup mouseout", function () {
  $(this).css({
    'font-size': '30px',
      'color': 'black'
  });
});
```