# How to make a change in the dom that lasts for one click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-manipulation

I am building a webpage and i have set a body `backround-image`. Is there a way to change the url of the image when the user presses the mouse key, and change it back when the mouse key is released? Basically the change lasts the same amount of time as the click itself.

Also, how do i make sure this change works for a click anywhere on the page?  Will adding an event listener to the body element suffice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to set and then re-set the background image.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207927/mouseup-and-mousedown

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but i have trouble phrasing the question so its hard to navigate through the answers

Comment: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated
>   by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it. On systems with more than one mouse button,
>   :active applies only to the primary or primary activation button
>   (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof.

[css3-selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act)

---

Pure CSS example:

```
body:active {
    background-image: [IMAGE];
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz31ov3k/1/)

Comment: Thanks ! The click part works but for some reason it won't work for any location on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alan Can you give us an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: It works on elements of the page (divs etc) but i want it (if possible) to work on other spots as well

Comment: @Alan But, if not the elements of the page, what else could those spots be?

Comment: Lets say my page is 1000x800. If the elements (so far) occupy only half of that , the remaiming space is blank and merely displays the backround image. This effect doesn't work on the blank space. It doesn't really matter, it's just out of curiosity

Comment: I assume you're directly setting the width of the body then. I suppose the only way to remedy that is the wrap the entire page in a container div, and set the width of that instead of the body. Then the body can stretch the entire width of the page to receive the clicks.