# confused with working of mouse events .onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, dom

here is HTML code

```
<div id="_navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>Destinations</li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Culture</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Adventure</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Hotels</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">Wild Life</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="_subNavigation">
                <div id="_navigationFirst">
                    this is first subnavigation it must be showed when user clicks on Distinations
                </div>
                <div id="_navigationSecond">
                    this is second subnavigation it must be showed when user clicks on Culture
                </div>
                <div id="_navigationThird">
                    this is third subnavigation it must be showed when user clicks on Adventure
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I apply some CSS on it after that it looks like this
[image]
forget other things in CSS...
in CSS div with id _subNavigation is set display:none;
Using java script i want that when someone clicks on Destination then _navigationFirst(it's an id) becames visible and when user takes mouse out of navigation region it goes out(became invisible)..
I am succeded in making it visible when user clicks on it but it doesn't goes out when user takes mouse out of navigation region.. Here is my javascipt

I get such desired image when i click on Destination
[image]

```
"use strict";
document.getElementById("_navigation").getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[0].onclick = function () {
    console.log("got into block");
    document.getElementById("_navigationFirst").style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementById("_navigation").onmouseleave = function () {
    console.log("you left _navigation block");
    document.getElementById("_navigationFirst").style.display = "none";
}
```

So **CodeGurus where am i wrong? and how to get effect that i am trying to get**

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("_navigation").onmouseout = function () {
    console.log("you left _navigation block");
    document.getElementById("_navigationFirst").style.display = "none";
}
```

Change it to "`onmouseout` ". I'm not sure "onmouseout" is the effect you want. You can look at [the difference between onmouseleave and onmouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave). If you need "onmouseleave" effect, you have to rely on jquery because javascript does not have built-in support for "onmouseleave". Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbJNP/) is here.