# Issue in vertical multi-level popup menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to develop a vertical multi-level popup menu. I am unable to set the child's top against to its parent `LI` position. The approach I took was, I am calculating `outerwidth of the UL tag and top of parent LI tag` for the respective left and top positions of the child tag. But It doesn't seem to work well.

If I set left and top using CSS, the first level looks good, but for the rest of the levels the top is always set to 0.

```
_pm.child.show().css({left:left-2,top:top-1});
```

And if I use the `position` function, all the levels are shown as very closer to its parent.

```
_pm.child.show().position({left:left-2,top:top-1});
```

What has gone wrong? Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDtCK/1/).

Comment: The wheel does not need re-inventing! http://jqueryui.com/menu/#default

Comment: Yeah... I know that jQuery Menu.But our requirement is some what different and what ever I have posted here is a sample piece of code only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the mouseout by mouseleave and it will work :)

Comment: Yeah buddy, U'r awesome.It does. But whatz the diff b/w mouseout nad mouseleave?And how does it impact on the left&top positions?

Comment: have a look here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave