# How to detect whether mouseout is true or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this simple fiddle as a working example-

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMNTB/)

I am trying to detect mouseout event from a `div` section. 
When i mouseover on this image it shows caption; saying "Change Image". After 5 seconds caption goes fadeOut.

I am using `setInterval` to set it accordingly. Now if I do mouseout of this image, then only I want Interval function should be called.

How do i detect mouseout event in jQuery?

**Tried-**

```
$(function () {
        $('.image-profile').mouseover(function () {
            $('.change-image').stop().show();

            if ($('.image-profile').mouseout()== true) {
                TimeOut();
            }
        });

        setInterval(function TimeOut() {
            $('.change-image').fadeOut()
        }, 5000

        );
    });
```

Comment: you already use `mouseover`, why would `mouseout` work any different?

Comment: + I bet you don't want to use `setInterval()` for this. Try `setTimeout()` instead.

Comment: @Yoshi, Just because i want to detect mouseout event, Using it is an another way of doing it.

Comment: @Manoz I think that's a simple misunderstanding on your side. Due to the async nature, handling events always involes callback functions.  You can maybe hide them or otherwise abstract them, but in the end a function will be called to handle the event.

Comment: @Manoz There can't be a mouseout event fired for the same element, ever, at a time when handling `mouseover`. The mouse has just entered to an element, how it would be possible to detect a mouseout from that element at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ImageProfileTimer;

$('.image-profile').on('mouseenter',function(){
    clearTimeout(ImageProfileTimer);
    $('.change-image').stop().show();
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    ImageProfileTimer = setTimeout(function(){
         $('.change-image').fadeOut()
    }, 5000);
});
```

Use setTimeout and clearTimeout

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xMNTB/9/

Comment: Can it be done without using another function of mouseleave? I want to detect if mouseout is true.

Comment: Yes, you can do it @Manoz just change mouseleave to mouseout

Comment: + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.image-profile').on('mouseleave', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.change-image').fadeOut()
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xMNTB/7/

Now the div show up on mouse enter and disappears 5 seconds after mouse leave.

```
$(function () {

    $('.image-profile').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.change-image').stop().show();
    });

    $('.image-profile').mouseleave(function () {
        setTimeout(function TimeOut() {
            $('.change-image').fadeOut()
        }, 5000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
(function () {
    $('.image-profile').mouseover(function () {
        $('.change-image').stop().show();

        if ($('.image-profile').mouseout() == true) {
            TimeOut();
        }
    }).mouseout(function () {
        setInterval(function TimeOut() {
            $('.change-image').fadeOut()
       }, 5000);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JqCCy/)